# Origin and Etymology of Kush/Cush in regards to animals

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown

I came across this word in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/agcGS0pdNGY?t=4m39s) (queued to example) and was curious about the origin.

[Example image of an alpaca kushing.](http://www.openherd.com/userPhotos/Large/2015_635642630643887986.jpg)

I can't find the definition as defined in the linked image in any dictionary. I tried a general Google search and various print dictionaries, including an (albeit dated) unabridged Oxford and a couple of (again, dated) American dictionaries. Surprisingly, the word did not appear at all in the Oxford.

The best I got was [this alpaca breeding website](http://www.stonespringsuri.com/index.php/alpaca-care/alpaca-terminology). It's described as a way of sitting either to keep warm or for females receptive to breeding. But none of the definitions I found related to that at all.

The definitions I **did** find most often were in regards to the biblical son of Ham (who was the son of Noah) and a region of Africa (possibly) named after him. For slang, it's another word for "money" and a type/preparation of marijuana similar to hashish.

Comment: I also can find nothing related to the action of an alpaca, except on alpaca websites.

Comment: Yes, *Kush* has been associated Biblically with Abyssinia, today Ethiopia. But alpaca and llama are New World animals, unknown to the Bible. This is where a seeming cognate is actually a false friend.

Answer (score 8):

***Kushing (or cushing or kooshing)*** is an awkward activity, because llamas only have two knees in the front and no knees in the back. Their back legs are joined at the hips!

***[Kush](http://www.llamapaedia.com/industry/terms.html)*** may derive from the sound of a command, probably from the French "couche" that is "lie down".

> - The term for the act of a llama laying down sternally or the actual position a llama is in when it is laying down. ***It may also be used as a command to get a llama to attain this position.***

(Llamapedia)

> - "[Kush](http://www.dragonflyllama.com/page14/page25/page79/page83/)" is a word used with camels to tell them to lie down. I'm sure it comes from the French "couche", but it rhymes with "push".

(Llama Training Manual)

***[Kush](http://www.nytimes.com/1987/12/21/us/sleepy-hollow-journal-to-trainer-llamas-are-not-just-fad.html)***:

> - ....a llama learns to leap, carry a pack, pull a little cart, pad alongside its owner on walks and ***respond to commands like ''kush,'' meaning ''lie down,'' from the French ''coucher.''***

(The New Your Times)